# Input of UITextField in CollectionViewCell (swift 3 xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, collectionview

I have a UITextField that I added within the subview of my collectionViewCell. Here is the code:

```
class ClientCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var width: CGFloat!
var height: CGFloat!

var textField: UITextField!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    width = bounds.width
    height = bounds.height
    setupViews()
}

func basicTextField(placeHolderString: String) -> UITextField {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderString, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)])
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textField
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: .black, thickness: 0.5)

    textField = basicTextField(placeHolderString: "name")

    addSubview(textField)

}

func buttonHandler() {

    if let textFieldInput = textField.text {
        print (textFieldInput)
    } else {
        print("Nothing in textField")
    }
}
```

}

I have a button in another class that calls this method, and at the moment prints the current input of the textField (which can be since in the buttonHandler() function). Problem is, the textField is always returning as empty for some reason and I'm not sure why.

EDIT:

this is the function the button calls when pressed (the button and its function are in a separate class to textField):

```
func testButton() {
    let test = ClientCell()
    test.handler()
}
```

SOLUTION:

The problem i was having was that I was making a new instance of my collectionViewCell in the class where I wanted the button to be pressed. When the function was called it would be empty.

To solve the problem i used NSNotificationCenter to make a post every time the button was tapped and had observers in the CollectionViewCell class that triggered a function when a post was made. Here is the code.

function called when button is pressed:

```
func saveData() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("saveProject"), object: nil)
}
```

code inside viewDidLoad of collectionViewCell:

```
class ClientCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handler), name: NSNotification.Name("saveProject"), object: nil)
}
```

finally, the function called by the observer in that class

```
func handler() {

    print(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method using button action, hope you are  not initializing this class object again while calling button action method. Share code of button action.

Comment: Just added it now.

Comment: so very obvious, it will always return you empty. Because you are initializing cell and creating new textfield in that class, so button action return you value of newly created text field.

Comment: if button do exist in same cell, then you should call its target same time. And if not, then you need to specify in button action code that you are calling text filed of which cell. Share your code of cell, then I might help you to write this. Also share your UI.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code in my Playgroud project. and it's work. So I think that your problem is not comping from this Class. 
here the code in playground :

```
func buttonHandler() {
    print(self.textField.text)
    if let textFieldInput = self.textField.text {
        print (textFieldInput)
    } else {
        print("Nothing in textField")
    }
}

let cell = ClientCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50 ))
cell.buttonHandler()
```

in console i have this

> Optional("")

with a empty ligne. (due to this print   "print (textFieldInput)"  )

Otherwise there is some stuff to fix in your code :

1) In "basicTextField" function : you need to specify the frame of the textField

```
let textField = UITextField(frame: YOUR_DESIRED_FRAME)
```

2) In "setupViews" function you should add the textField in content View of your Cell :

```
contentView.addSubview(textField)
```

Comment: But shouldn't i be getting the result of the user input? When i run my app, I put a string into the textfield, tap the button and get exactly that "optional("")" in console.  I thought it would print the users input.

Comment: in your "testButton()" you should use ClientCell(frame:) initialiser to setup your cell view